# regularly/occasionally/sometimes

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adverbs

Let's say I dine out once every month.

I don't suppose one could say I dine out often, but I dine out regularly although infrequently.

Could one say I dine out occasionally/on occasion/now and again?
Could one say I dine sometimes dine out?

I'd say 'sometimes' would work bu the others don't.

Many thanks

Comment: _Occasionally_ and similar expressions imply that it happens at _irregular_ intervals.

Answer (score 1):

All these words express an opinion, your opinion, about the frequency of dining out.  Do you think that once a month is more than would be expected (for a person in your situation)?  Do you think that the person you are talking to would expect you to dine out more frequently or less frequently?

There is **no rule** about how frequent "often" or "sometimes" or "occasionally"  mean.  All these term are relative to cultural or individual standards and expectations.

Therefore, depending on the cultural expectations of you and and your assumptions about the people you are talking to, you could use "often", "sometimes", "now and again" or "occasionally". This is a choice that you must make.